# How should i export jar when they depend on each other?

Tags: java, jar

If I have 3 java projects: A, B and C

Where A use classes from B, and B use classes from C

How should I export the project A?

Should I export C, add it to the project B and then export B and add it the jar to A?

And if I have to update C, I have to repeat what I have done before?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "export the project"? Do you use a build system like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: yes, I use maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can add both to project A**

You don't have to **add C to B** and **B to A**,
You can **add C and B to A**

Your jar file will look the same if you **add C to B and then B to A** or **add C and B to A**

Answer (score 0):

Considering the tags java and jar. All you need is to have **b.jar** and **c.jar** in the classpath of **a.jar**.

Just export the 3 jar and run on this way:

```
java -classpath b.jar;c.jar;a.jar package.mainclass
```

But it's wrong to say that they depend of each other. When it happens it is like a depends b that depends a. It's an error and it can't happen.